# Arduino: Generating 100 int random array results in first 10 integers of 0

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I am using an Arduino UNO with 32.000 bytes of storage. 
While writing my program I made a small function that filled an array with random numbers.
This function uses a variable I defined at the top of the script as:

```
int mode1[100];
```

And this is the function that fills the array above. RandomSeed takes a number for its seed, whcih is provided by analogRead(0), with the 0 meaning pin 0 on my Arduino board.

```
void fillArray(int aSize){
    if (aSize == 100){
        randomSeed(analogRead(0));
        for (int i=0; i < aSize; i++){
            mode1[i] = random(1, aSize);}
```

When I call the fillArray function like fillArray(100); it will generate my integers. I then read them on my computer via this piece of code:

```
  Serial.println("Filled array");
  for (int i=0; i <= 99; i++){Serial.println((int)mode1[i]);}
```

Everything seemed to work fine but I noticed that the first 10 integers that my function will generate are always 0. My main problem is that I don't know how to troubleshoot this because the script gives me no errors. My question therefore is: What is the cause of the first 10 integers of that array always being 0?

My possible explanations for the cause are that the AnalogRead function does something strange (Currently it just has a pin in the A0 slot with nothing connected to it, which *should* work. I also know it's not the storage capacity, since 32.000 bytes is enough to store 100 integers in an array, and my script is only 5000 bytes.

I'm a bit stuck on this because I do not know what is causing the problem, any help would on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the rest of the output always the same? Also can you test it by setting the randomSeed to 5000 manually and seeing if you get similar results (first 10 are 0's)?

I chose 5000 since it is outside the range that AnalogRead will return.

Comment: `0` cannot be returned when `random` is called like this: `random(1, aSize);`...

Comment: Do you have any code that runs AFTER the array is filled? I suspect maybe something is corrupting your array...

Comment: After the array is filled, it's the for loop that prints every element of the array. That's it!

And to answer Fiddling Bits; that's a very important thing I didn't think about. It's weird that it's adding 0 to the array then when I'm calling random(1, aSize), since the minimum should be 1 obviously then.

Comment: Try reducing the size of the array to 50 and see what happens.

Comment: You might also want to print out each random number as it's generated. I suspect something is corrupted memory. If the loop that is generating the random numbers always generates proper non-zero numbers then later your array appears to have 0's then you can be certain you have a case of memory corruption.

Comment: Minor: `for (int i=0; i < aSize; i++)` is less confusing than `for (int i=0; i <= (aSize-1); i++)`

Comment: FYI, 32K is your program memory.  You only have 2K of RAM for runtime storage, and some of that is taken by things like serial buffers.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment (not enough reputation yet), but did you check the number of lines that are on your output ? You may have "something" else in your code sending data before your start your log. You may want to write lines with "mode1[*xxx*]= *yyy*" where *xxx* is the index and *yyy* the value stored at index to make sure you that are looking at your array content.